# Distinct values by multiple columns after already applied GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically, I have the following query (actually more complex, but I think this simplification is ok):

```
SELECT a, b, x
FROM table

output:

 a | b | x
-----------
 1 | 2 | 34
 1 | 3 | 35
 1 | 3 | 36
 1 | 4 | 37
 2 | 3 | 38
 2 | 3 | 39
 2 | 4 | 40
 3 | 4 | 41
 3 | 5 | 42
```

To count the number of occurrence of each "pair of a and b", I'm using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(x) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY count

output:

 a | b | count
--------------
 1 | 2 | 1
 1 | 4 | 1
 2 | 4 | 1
 3 | 4 | 1
 3 | 5 | 1
 1 | 3 | 2
 2 | 3 | 2
```

What bothers me is the multiple occurence of a and b. I would like to keep the "count" as it is, but remove every following row, if a or b was already in a previous row. It would be a nice to have, if it would also remove a row, if the value of "a" appeared in a previous row as "b" and vice versa.

**Preferred expected output:**

```
 a | b | count
--------------
 1 | 2 | 1
 1 | 4 | 1    <- should not be in output since we had a=1
 2 | 4 | 1    <- should not be in output since we had b=
 3 | 4 | 1    
 3 | 5 | 1    <- should not be in output since we had a=3
 1 | 3 | 2    <- should not be in output since we had a=1 / a=3
 2 | 3 | 2    <- should not be in output since we had b=2 / a=3
```

Therefore, this:

```
 a | b | count
--------------
 1 | 2 | 1
 3 | 4 | 1
```

**Alternative expected output**, if the above would be too complex:

```
 a | b | count
--------------
 1 | 2 | 1
 1 | 4 | 1    <- should not be in output since we had a=1
 2 | 4 | 1    
 3 | 4 | 1    <- should not be in output since we had b=4
 3 | 5 | 1    
 1 | 3 | 2    <- should not be in output since we had a=1
 2 | 3 | 2    <- should not be in output since we had a=2
```

Therefore, this:

```
 a | b | count
--------------
 1 | 2 | 1
 2 | 4 | 1    
 3 | 5 | 1
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: It seems to me like you'd want two queries...one for a count of a and another one for a count of b. It's not making much sense to run them in the same query if you're not actually looking for a count of a AND b.  (From your desired output, you're not actually looking for occurrences of a AND b).

Comment: I actually want a count of how many a specific combination of a and b occurs, and need to get the first n rows with the lowest count. Those combinations are presented to the user, but the user should not get "bored" by getting the same a or b presented again and again. If you are interested, you can take a look at the complete query / output at https://dataclips.heroku.com/mjpbdqkuljzvimgklsvfnrnqkdib-Example-for-Stackoverflow-question, but I think that this is way to specific for a SO question

Comment: When you have multiple rows with the same COUNT, how do you decide which order to display them in?

Comment: The same order which is already achieved after the first ORDER BY, so it should first output the rows with the lowest count. It should only remove subsequent rows, which contain the value for a / b again, independent from the count of the other row.

Comment: Based on your description, it is not possible to ensure that results simultaneously include *both* for each `a`, an (a,b) pair among those for that `a` having lowest count, *and* for each `b`, an (a,b) pair among those for that `b` having lowest count.  In fact, it may be that some `a`s or `b`s participating in very low-count pairs are not represented at all.  Is that ok?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to relax your constraints so that `a` and / or `b` values could appear twice (but no more)?

Comment: The count for each pair is always increasing my application, so the most important thing is that pairs with the lowest count are always preferred. (The returned pairs are in fact those, which will be processed and after that have an increased count). If one pair does not get returned in favour of another pair with the same (or a lower) count this would not matter.

Comment: Appearing one value just twice sounds like a good compromise, yes

Comment: As I made a mistake with the dataclip in comment 4, I needed to delete the old query since heroku keeps a history of the versions. Updated link: https://dataclips.heroku.com/dybvfwpazelxtedbycwoscuovzql-Example-for-Stackoverflow-question?result=latest&version=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather a mess of a problem, but here's something to consider:

```
SELECT a, b, count
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, count,
          rank() over (partition by b order by count, a) as b_rank
    FROM (
        SELECT a, b, count,
          rank() over (partition by a order by count, b) as a_rank
        FROM (
            SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM t
            GROUP BY a, b
            ORDER BY count
          ) pc
      ) pc2
    WHERE a_rank < 3
  ) pc3
WHERE b_rank = 1
```

Each `a` value will appear at most twice in the results, but `b` values will be unique.  Some `b` values appearing in low-count pairs may not be reflected in the results.  There is a trade-off between possible duplication of `a` and the number of `b` values that may be missed altogether: allowing more duplicates of `a` (by changing to, e.g, `WHERE a_rank < 4`) reduces the number of `b` values that may be missed.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. Since I posted a link to heroku dataclips in the comments above, you might be interested in how the actual query / output looks: https://dataclips.heroku.com/dybvfwpazelxtedbycwoscuovzql-Example-for-Stackoverflow-question?result=latest&version=3

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the desired output.

```
DECLARE @id INT = 1,
        @a INT,
        @b INT,
        @count INT

DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    a INT,
    b INT,
    count INT
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT a, b, COUNT(1) AS COUNT FROM dbo.myTable
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY COUNT,a,b

SELECT @count = COUNT(1) FROM @tbl

WHILE @id <= @count
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @a = a,@b = b FROM @tbl WHERE id = @id

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl WHERE id < @id AND (a = @a OR b = @b))
        DELETE @tbl WHERE id = @id

    SET @id += 1
END

SELECT a,b,count FROM @tbl
```

[Check it on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b478a/5)